# Pressing both shift keys together for correct output

Tags: keyboard

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 which I use for work. At random intervals, the shift keys on the laptop will take turns to fail. It only happens for a few keys, namely "T, Y, {, }, !, @, #, $, &, *, (, )".

When I hold both shift keys down at the same time, and press that key, it works properly.

I hope this isn't a hardware issue, but if it is a software issue, how do I begin to troubleshoot?

Comment: Go to Control Panel, Accessibility Features. Ensure all features are off, restart and test.

Comment: ^ This, and especially check if sticky keys are enabled and disable it if that's the case.

Comment: Are you sure that both keys were required, or that only one of the two was functional?

Comment: @harrymc, yes, there are times when both shift keys do not work, and that is the only way to get the correct output

Comment: @John The problem persists on the linux OS as well though..but I will give that a shot

Answer (score 0):

The fact that this also happens under Linux means that this is not a software problem.

There are only a few things that you can do, in order:

- [Deep clean the keyboard](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-clean-your-keyboard)
- Replace the keyboard
- Send the laptop to be repaired.